# SimpleXML Accessing Elements - PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, simplexml

I am trying to get inside of `<err:Errors>` located in the SOAP below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>An exception has been raised as a result of client data.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <err:Errors xmlns:err="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Error/v1.1">
                    <err:ErrorDetail>
                        <err:Severity>Hard</err:Severity>
                        <err:PrimaryErrorCode>
                            <err:Code>120802</err:Code>
                            <err:Description>Address Validation Error on ShipTo address</err:Description>
                        </err:PrimaryErrorCode>
                    </err:ErrorDetail>
                </err:Errors>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is how I am trying to do it but $fault_errors->Errors doesn't have anything.

```
$nameSpaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$soap = $xml->children($nameSpaces['soapenv']);
$fault_errors = $soap->Body->children($nameSpaces['err']);

if (isset($fault_errors->Errors)) {
    $faultCode = (string) $fault_errors->ErrorDetail->PrimaryErrorCode->Code;               
}
```

Comment: Note that your code now relies on the 'soapenv' prefix, which is a very bad practice!

Comment: Yes. Basically the used prefix should be ignored by parsers. If the prefix of an xml namespace changes over night, then the semantic meaning of your xml document stays the same, and your parser should not break. The namespace url remains stable though, so hardcode that in, instead of the prefix.

Comment: @Evert Makes sense. I will certainly do that from now on. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search with XPath:

```
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('err', $ns['err']);

$errors = $xml->xpath("//err:Errors");
echo $errors[0]->saveXML(); // prints the tree
```

Comment: So do I access? like this? $severity = (string)$errors[0]->ErrorDetail->Severity;

Comment: @Slinky No, more like this: `(string)current($errors[0]->xpath("err:ErrorDetail/err:Severity")`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to jump down several steps in the XML at once. The `->` operator and `->children()` method just return *direct children*, not arbitrary descendants.

As stated in the other answer, you can use XPath to jump down, but if you do want to traverse, you need to pay attention to the namespace of each node you pass, and call `->children()` again when it changes.

The below code breaks it down step by step ([live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UVwc2y)):

```
$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml);
// These are all in the "soapenv" namespace
$soap_fault = $sx->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->Fault;
// These are in the (undeclared) default namespace (a mistake in the XML being sent)
echo (string)$soap_fault->children(null)->faultstring, '<br />';
$fault_detail = $soap_fault->children(null)->detail;
// These are in the "err" namespace
$inner_fault_code = (string)$fault_detail->children('http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Error/v1.1')->Errors->ErrorDetail->PrimaryErrorCode->Code;               
echo $inner_fault_code, '<br />';
```

Of course, you can do some or all of that in one go:

```
$inner_fault_code = (string)
    $sx
    ->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->Fault
    ->children(null)->detail
    ->children('http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Error/v1.1')->Errors->ErrorDetail->PrimaryErrorCode->Code;               
echo $inner_fault_code, '<br />';
```